# How to solve the problem to use request.user in custom profile fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**- models.py**

**As you can see all code here. I want the user after athenticate had filled the all profile fields
but there is 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error.**

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import *
   
   
   
 class UserProfileForm(UserCreationForm):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
   
  class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = ProfileModel
          fields = ['name', 'age', 'city', 'country']
```

**views.py**

**The userprofile is success and when profile  request is post then the error arise**

```
def userprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('App_Login:profile'))
     else:
         form = UserProfileForm()
     return render(request, 'App_Login/userprofile.html', {'form': form})
   
   
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            reg = ProfileModel(name=name, age=age, city=city, country=country)
            reg.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'App_Login/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Before redirecting to user profile view first authenticate the user properly so that `request.user` will return user instance.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

......
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   user = authenticate(request, username=form.cleaned_data['username'],password=form.cleaned_data['password2'])
   if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('App_Login:profile'))
```